# Calling javascript functions using javascriptcore framework returns [object Object] to JSValue

Tags: javascript, ios, objective-c, javascriptcore

Code in `.js` file:

```
var fact = function(x){
    return WeatherWebService(x);
}
```

objective-c native methods:

```
 - (IBAction)btnOkClicked:(id)sender 
    {
        [self.aJSEngine loadJSLibrary:@"script"];    
    }

    - (void)loadJSLibrary:(NSString*)libraryName
    {
        NSString *library = [NSString stringWithContentsOfFile:[[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:libraryName ofType:@"js"]  encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding error:nil];

        NSLog(@"[JSC] loading library %@...", libraryName);
        [self runJS:library];
    }

    - (void)runJS:(NSString *)aJSString
    {
        if (!aJSString) {
            NSLog(@"[JSC] JS String is empty!");
        }
        else{
            JSContext *context = [[JSContext alloc]initWithVirtualMachine:[[JSVirtualMachine alloc]init]];
            context[@"WeatherWebService"] = ^(int x){
                NSDictionary *dict = [self callingWeatherFromJavascript];
                return dict;
            };

            [context evaluateScript:aJSString];
            JSValue *val = context[@"fact"];
            JSValue *finalResult = [val callWithArguments:@[context[@"3"]]];

        }
    }

    -(NSDictionary*)callingWeatherFromJavascript{
            NSString *urlString =  @"http://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?q=London,uk";
            NSURLRequest *request = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:urlString]];
            __block BOOL complete = NO;
            AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation = [[AFHTTPRequestOperation alloc] initWithRequest:request];
            operation.responseSerializer = [AFJSONResponseSerializer serializer];

            [operation setCompletionBlockWithSuccess:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, id responseObject) {

                // 3
                self.dictionary = (NSDictionary *)responseObject;
                complete=YES;
                // NSDictionary *dict = [self.dictionary objectForKey:@"main"];
                //            if ([self.delegate respondsToSelector:@selector(returnDataFromResponse:)]) {
                //                [self.delegate returnDataFromResponse:dict];
                //            }

            } failure:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, NSError *error) {

                // 4
                UIAlertView *alertView = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Error Retrieving Weather"
                                                                    message:[error localizedDescription]
                                                                   delegate:nil
                                                          cancelButtonTitle:@"Ok"
                                                          otherButtonTitles:nil];
                complete=NO;
                [alertView show];
            }];


            // 5
            [operation start];
        while(complete == NO) {
            [[NSRunLoop currentRunLoop] runMode:NSDefaultRunLoopMode beforeDate:[NSDate dateWithTimeIntervalSinceNow:0.1]];
        }
        return self.dictionary;
    }
```

In the above code, the  method `'callingWeatherFromJavascript'` returns `NSDictionary`. When i receive this value in "JSValue" in function `'-(void)runJS'` it returns `[object Object]`.  Is there any way of converting this back into `NSDictionary`?

Comment: What is [object Object]? Is it JSON, XML or something else?

Comment: NSDictionary kind of object.

Comment: give me some example data and I will let you know how to convert it back to NSDictionary

Comment: id = 2643743; base = "cmc stations";
    clouds =     {
        all = 36;
    };
    cod = 200;
    main =     {
        "grnd_level" = "1013.19";
        humidity = 78;
        pressure = "1013.19";
        "sea_level" = "1023.2";
        temp = "284.491";
        "temp_max" = "284.491";
        "temp_min" = "284.491";
    };

Comment: this is what i want in above format

Comment: OK let me see if I understood right. Your are evaluating some JavaScript, and this JS returns an object that you want to convert back to NSDictionary. Is that correct, or you want to modify your object in JS to look like NSDictionary in Objective C? Which one is it?

Comment: yes JS returns an object that i want to convert back to NSDictionary.

Comment: Did you try `[finalResult toDictionary]`?

Answer (score 2):

I don't want to take credit away from vivek_ios, he answered his own question. I just want to rewrite his response so it's clearer and easier to re-use because it took me a while to find the answer in the comments.

Basically, converting JSValue to NSDictionary is simply done via JSValue.toDictionary. Something like this:

```
JSContext *jsContext  = [JSContext new];
[jsContext evaluateScript:[NSString stringWithContentsOfFile:myJavascriptFilePath encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding error:nil]];
NSDictionary *result = [jsContext[@"myJavascriptFunction"] callWithArguments:@[optionalArgument]].toDictionary;
```

Answer (score 0):

First covert your response object to NSData

```
NSData *responseData = [[NSData alloc]initWithContentsOfFile:(NSString*)responseObject encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding error:nil];
```

Then create NSDictionary with JSON serialization as it looks like you are receiving JSON object from your webservice

```
NSDictionary *responceDictionary = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:responseData options:kNilOptions error:nil];
```

Then you should be able to access your "main" key and get all info from here.

Comment: i just explored a little bit on JavaScriptCore framework, i really found a very easy way of doing this.                                      [context evaluateScript:aJSString];
        JSValue *val = context[@"fact"];
        JSValue *finalResult = [val callWithArguments:@[context[@"3"]]];
        NSDictionary *responceDictionary = finalResult.toDictionary; there is a function called toDictionary to convert javascript object to NSDictionary